# How can I get ADO to recognize all dates in a .csv file as US dates?

Tags: sql, vba, ado

I have a MS Access DB called `*your path*\Test\Test.accdb`
It contains a table called `Table1`

I have two `.csv` files:

- “your path\Test\Test_Data_20190111.csv”
- “your path\Test\Test_Data_20190114.csv”

with the date data stored in US format as follows:

```
Date(MM/DD/YYYY),TestField  
1/11/2019,C  
1/11/2019,D
```

and

```
Date(MM/DD/YYYY),TestField
1/14/2019,A
1/14/2019,B
```

I upload the data from the .csv files using the VBA code below (using an ADODB.Recordset),

```vb
Sub Upload_CSV_to_MSDB()

Dim xlcon As ADODB.Connection
Dim xlrs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strFile_Path_Name As String
Dim cnStr As String

' Set ADO object variable
Set xlcon = New ADODB.Connection
Set xlrs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Set string variables
strFile_Path_Name = "your path \Test\"
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 IN ' your path \Test\Test.accdb' " & _
            "SELECT  [Date(MM/DD/YYYY)], [TestField] " & _
            "FROM Test_Data_20190111.csv"

' Set connection string to CSV file
cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & strFile_Path_Name & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"""

' Execute strSQl by opening record set
xlrs.Open strSQL, cnStr, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Set xlrs = Nothing
Set xlcon = Nothing

End Sub
```

When I upload the data for the file Test_Data_20190111.csv ADO recognises the date stored as UK format, but for Test_Data_20190114.csv the dates are recognized as US format, as there is no month 14.

How can I run something similar to the code above and have it recognize any dates in a `.csv` file as US format? Note that the data has dates in US format but my regional computer settings are UK date format; I don’t want to change these regional settings.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you change the way the csv files are generated ?

Comment: @reportgunner No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so long since I did this I forget the exact details. However I believe you need to use a Schema.ini file.

In the directory where the csv files are, add a file call Schema.ini with a section for each file. The settings of the section allow you to specify the format of each column something like this:

```
[Test_Data_20190111.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
DateTimeFormat=MM/DD/YYYY
Col1=Date(MM/DD/YYYY) DateTime
Col2=TestField Text

[Test_Data_20190114.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
DateTimeFormat=MM/DD/YYYY
Col1=Date(MM/DD/YYYY) DateTime
Col2=TestField Text
```

For more details see Microsoft's Documentation on [Scehma.ini files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Actually, I’ve mucked around a bit with shema.ini files before, I didn’t think of it. I’ll give it a go and let you know. Thanks for the prompt.

Comment: Feel free to update the answer if I have any of the details wrong.